# Cannot define analyzer in hibernate search 6

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I define an analyzer on hibernate search 6

```java
public class MyLuceneAnalysisConfigurer implements LuceneAnalysisConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configure(LuceneAnalysisConfigurationContext context) {
        context.analyzer( "english" ).custom()
                .tokenizer( StandardTokenizerFactory.class )
                .charFilter( HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.class )
                .tokenFilter( LowerCaseFilterFactory.class )
                .tokenFilter( SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class )
                .param( "language", "English" )
                .tokenFilter( ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class );
        ;


        context.analyzer( "french" ).custom()
                .tokenizer( StandardTokenizerFactory.class )
                .charFilter( HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.class )
                .tokenFilter( LowerCaseFilterFactory.class )
                .tokenFilter( SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class )
                .param( "language", "French" )
                .tokenFilter( ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class );
    }
}
```

After I add this to `application.properties`:

```
hibernate.search.backend.indexes.<Product>.analysis.configurer = com.example.springmvcrest.services.MyLuceneAnalysisConfigurer
```

but its not resolved by IntelliJ,

and after running:

```
 Analyzer not found org.hibernate.search.util.common.SearchException: HSEARCH000353: Unknown analyzer: 'english'. Make sure you defined this analyzer.
```

Any solution? I use spring boot 2.4.0

Comment: Same exact problem I am seeing, with very similar configuration.
Though I have this in application.property:
{code}spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.backend.analysis.configurer={code}
Based on what is mentioned here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started-analysis

Comment: @Jubz The file is named `application.properties`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

In your `application.properties`, change this

```
hibernate.search.backend.indexes.<Product>.analysis.configurer
```

to:

```
hibernate.search.backend.analysis.configurer
```

In summary:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.backend.analysis.configurer=com.example.springmvcrest.services.MyLuceneAnalysisConfigurer
```

Source: [Hibernate Search 6.0.1.Final: Reference Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-lucene-analysis)